# what is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$, where $a_i$ is independent Gaussian variable with zero mean and $b_i$ variance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

If all the variance of all the Gaussian variables are the same, saying 1, then the distribution is Chi-squared https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution.

In my question, the variance are different, so could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can it be assumed that the variables have zero mean?

Answer (score 0):

The same [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Linear_combination) states that no closed form expression for this distribution is known.  See "Generalizations" section, "Linear combinations" subsection.  Yours is equivalent to the described case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a weighted sum of $\chi_1^2$ random variables, i.e.

$$S_n\equiv\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\stackrel{D}{=}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i Z_i^2,$$

where $Z_i$'s are i.i.d standard normal. $S_n$ does not have a closed form CDF. But using the inversion of its ch.f. the CDF of $S_n$ [is given by](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU-pO5-sbLAhVW7mMKHZoQDOkQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fntrs.nasa.gov%2Farchive%2Fnasa%2Fcasi.ntrs.nasa.gov%2F19680015093.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG8wTRPv43rdsARnkISy93nUnIDkw&sig2=WqYivID9lvvx_-Kdq2QPtg)

$$
F_{S_n}(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx/2)}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n \tan^{-1}(2b_jt)-tx\right)\prod_{j=1}^n(1+4b_j^2t^2)^{-1/4}dt.
$$